# Namespaces and C++ library

Tags: c++, namespaces, standard-library

Is a namespace contained in a library or a library is contained in a namespace?
How many namespaces are there in the C++ standard library ?

Comment: They are orthogonal.  One library can have several namespaces.  One namespace can be in several libraries.

Comment: @user17372522 so should I consider that the standard library is written under std namespace or the std namespace is written inside the standard library ??

Comment: Neither.  The C++ standard explicitly allows other libraries to add to the std namespace.  (in specific circumstances).  Not all of the standard library is in the std namespace.  Not all of the std namespace is in the standard library.  That's what "orthogonal" means - they are unrelated concepts.  You should not try to describe one in terms of the other.

Comment: @DrewDormann so that means there are some libraries too which uses std namespace and there are other namespaces in standard library except only std ?

Comment: I believe both of those questions are answered in the _answer_ you accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are orthogonal. A library can use multiple namespaces and a namespace can be split between multiple libraries. However it is a good practice to scope the contents of a library to a (usually single) namespace (+ namespaces nested therein) specific to that library to avoid name clash between multiple libraries and for clarity.

The standard library uses (aside from the global namespace scope) only the `std` namespace (+ nested namespaces), although namespaces named `std` followed by any number of digits and the namespace `posix` are also reserved to the standard library for future standardization. The standard library also has multiple nested namespaces inside `std`, e.g. `std::filesystem` and `std::ranges`, and certain names are reserved for it in the global namespace scope.

The standard library also explicitly allows user code (including user libraries) to add certain declarations (in particular partial specializations of some classes) to the `std` namespace. So `std` is not always completely restricted to the standard library either.

Comment: There is also sub namespaces, like `filesystem` and `experimental`